# Can we access the old app_id after migration to high replication datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

Once we upgrade our application from Master Slave to the high replication datastore, we plan on aliasing the current MS app_id to the HR version.

Will we able to access the old site somehow? I assume $APP_ID.appspot.com will not work since we'll have aliased that app_id. Is there a way to get to $OLD_APP_ID.appspot.com after aliasing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration tool offers to create just such an alias for you.  So you won't have to access the old app to do this.  The admin console for the old app remains accessible, but if you use the alias, you can't access the old app via .appspot.com.  OTOH if you don't let the tool create an alias, you have full access to the old app.

Comment: [Please look at my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768891). I have not completed the migration, so I wonder if I can undo the alias request and still get the new app combined with the existing data. I was forced to migrate because the original google-maps app stopped acknowledging map rightclicks which were essential.