# Entity keys are different after migration to High Replication Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My migration to hrd is not working on appspot.com . The app datastore has 3 "kind"s of data in both the original master/slave (MS) and in the High Replication Datastore (hrd): `Group`, Pin, and Log. Each `Group` entity has Pin entities and/or Log entities associated with it, but the associations no longer work in the hrd (which is all that survives the migration), so my app no longer works and I am looking for help to revive it.

Below I report the entity keys for the first two `Pin` entities in the datastore. I have inserted some spaces in the shorter key of each pair to facilitate lining up the keys to see their similarities. Notice that all the keys start and end similarly, but differ in MS vs hrd.

```
Decoded entity key: Group: name=250cc > Pin: id=1
Entity #1 MS  key: ah        NzaW1wbGlmeWNvbm5lY3Rpb25zchkLEgVHcm91cCIFMjUwY2MMCxIDUGluGAEM
Entity #1 hrd key: ahlzfnNpbXBsaWZ5Y29ubmVjdGlvbnMtaHJkchkLEgVHcm91cCIFMjUwY2MMCxIDUGluGAEM


Decoded entity key: Group: name=250cc > Pin: id=5001
Entity #2 MS   key: ah        NzaW1wbGlmeWNvbm5lY3Rpb25zchoLEgVHcm91cCIFMjUwY2MMCxIDUGluGIknDA
Entity #2 hrd  key: ahlzfnNpbXBsaWZ5Y29ubmVjdGlvbnMtaHJkchoLEgVHcm91cCIFMjUwY2MMCxIDUGluGIknDA
```

[To view the app yourself](http://simplifyconnections.appspot.com/?place=Playground) use this link. You will see the `Group` named "Playground" and see how it is called in the URL. However, the only markers (map pins) that appear are ones that were added since the migration to hrd.

**edit #0**

Below is my Python code for adding saving a `Pin` where the parent is a `Group`.

```
elif action == "add":
            pin = Pin(parent=place)
            pin.name = self.request.get('details')
            pin.lat = float(self.request.get('lat'))
            pin.lng = float(self.request.get('lng'))
            pin.category = int(self.request.get('category'))
            pin.label = self.request.get('label')
            new_id = pin.put()
            self.response.out.write(new_id)
```

And below is the class definition for `Pin`.

```
class Pin(db.Model):
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    lat = db.FloatProperty()
    lng = db.FloatProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    cornerColor  = db.StringProperty(default='ffffff')
    height = db.IntegerProperty(default=32)
    label = db.StringProperty(default='')
    labelColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    labelSize = db.IntegerProperty(default=2)
    primaryColor = db.StringProperty(default='ff0000')
    shadowColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    shape = db.StringProperty(default='circle')
    strokeColor = db.StringProperty(default='000000')
    width = db.IntegerProperty(default=32)
    category = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    scategory = db.StringProperty()
    logindex = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    imageindex = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    deleteRequested = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

**edit #0**

**edit #1**

The problem with my app is not with the entity keys, after all. Instead, the problem is with the way I tried to handle another deprecated Google (Maps) feature regarding stylized markers in my javascript/html.

I am sorry for the noise here. The problem resulted from my inability/ineptness with a try..catch pattern I attempted to employ as a workaround in the javascript/html template.

**edit #1**

Comment: This probably is better suited for an App Engine production ticket so that someone can dig into the data. I would recommend filing a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: Its not a bug. Its well documented in the migration guide that manually saved ids dont migrate as all ids will change in hdr.

Comment: What was "manually saved" about the process I used? I used the appengine automated process (as we discussed here in SO)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768891/].

Comment: It probably comes down to how you store your references in different Entities. The automatic migration tool should handle any properties stored as Datastore keys. However, if you store anything only by id or as a serialized key, you'll have to manually migrate them: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration#migrating_serialized_datastore_keys.

Comment: Please look at the edited question for code I added. Is there a problem there? It worked fine for Master/Slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoded key strings are expected to change. The encoded version contain the application's Id. During the migration process the keys are re-written with the new application Id. References to keys are also similarly updated.

If you store a key as a db.ReferenceProperty, the key is automatically updated for you during the migration.

However if you are storing strings like

> ahNzaW1wbGlmeWNvbm5lY3Rpb25zchkLEgVHcm91cCIFMjUwY2MMCxIDUGluGAEM

in db.StringProperty() (or other similar ways, such as a part of a URL), then they will not be updated an you need to update yourself as [described in the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration#migrating_serialized_datastore_keys).

The model you reference for Pin, does not appear to link to other entities so there shouldn't be any problems.